# vpnc has stopped working with Cisco VPN gateway Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: network-manager, vpn, vpnc, libgcrypt

Recently I've been unable to connect to a Cisco VPN gateway using `vpnc` even though I had been using `vpnc` to connect to this same gateway for about a year leading up to this breakage... I'm using the command line client, not NetworkManager.

Strangely, sometimes if I reboot and try again it works... However, tonight I tried that a few times and never got through...

I see the following messages in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Aug 21 22:44:56 sonbuntu NetworkManager[1193]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Aug 21 22:44:56 sonbuntu NetworkManager[1193]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Aug 21 22:44:56 sonbuntu NetworkManager[1193]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Aug 21 22:47:06 sonbuntu avahi-daemon[1116]: Withdrawing workstation service for tun0.
Aug 21 22:47:06 sonbuntu NetworkManager[1193]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Aug 21 22:48:08 sonbuntu NetworkManager[1193]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Aug 21 22:48:08 sonbuntu NetworkManager[1193]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Aug 21 22:48:08 sonbuntu NetworkManager[1193]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
```

When I `strace` it, it seems to hang around here:

```
time(NULL)                              = 1377150323
times({tms_utime=8, tms_stime=1, tms_cutime=0, tms_cstime=0}) = 1717972828
gettimeofday({1377150323, 725505}, NULL) = 0
getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={0, 88000}, ru_stime={0, 16000}, ...}) = 0
time(NULL)                              = 1377150323
times({tms_utime=8, tms_stime=1, tms_cutime=0, tms_cstime=0}) = 1717972828
time(NULL)                              = 1377150323
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 96000) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 192000^C <unfinished ...>
```

My version of `vpnc` hasn't changed since I originally installed it:

```
Version: 0.5.3r512-2ubuntu1
```

However, I did notice that one of its dependencies, `libgcrypt11`, did recently change:

```
Version: 1.5.0-3ubuntu2.2
```

(used to be `1.5.0-3ubuntu1`).

As I see it there could be a few different possibilities about why this has broken:

1. `libgcrypt11` broke it
2. Some Ubuntu kernel configuration broke it (`/var/log/syslog` is complaining about a lacking driver...)
3. Something changed on the gateway's end (I plan on asking IT if they've changed anything but it will be very hard to actually get connected to the right person for this)

Should I try to roll back `libgcrypt11`? Any other ideas? Why is `/var/log/syslog` complaining about a missing driver?

---

I've tried some of the responses to [this similar-looking vpnc problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144205/cisco-vpn-not-working) but to no avail...

---

**Update** It appears to be a bug in `libgcrypt11=1.5.0-3ubuntu2.2`. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there must be a bug in `libgcrypt11=1.5.0-3ubuntu2.2`. After rolling back to `libgcrypt11=1.5.0-3ubuntu2.1` things are working again...

```
sudo apt-get install libgcrypt11=1.5.0-3ubuntu2.1
```

I've filed a [bug report on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libgcrypt11/+bug/1217183).

Comment: This one may have come back to haunt us in 14.04 LTS:

<warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...

Comment: yes can confirm!

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting exactly the same thing happening. My Cisco VPN was working last week, but fails now. I downgraded libgcrypt11 to 1.5.0-3ubuntu2.1 but that doesn't resolve the problem for me.

Anybody else having issues with this?

Comment: try `strace`'ing vpnc to see where it freezes.

Answer (score 1):

For me the cause of VPN not working anymore was that my stored passwords where somehow wrong although I didn't change them.
I found that out by starting NetworkManager VPNC in the shell using the following command (in Siduction, that is, but I guess it might be similar in Ubuntu):

```
sudo /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-vpnc-service --debug
```

Then I started the VPNC connection as usual via NetworkManager tray icon - the debug output can be seen on the console.

For me it showed (on the bottom):

```
/usr/sbin/vpnc: hash comparison failed:  (ISAKMP_N_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED)(24)
check group password!
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and tried the downgrade of `libcrypt11` ... fresh install of 14.04.2 LTS 64-bit, and so the downgrade was not in the repository and I had to download the deb and use `dpkg` to install it:

```
curl http://launchpadlibrarian.net/122471093/libgcrypt11_1.5.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb >lc.deb
sudo dpkg -i lc.deb
```

The downgrade didn't work, however when I ran the client in debug mode:

```
sudo /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-vpnc-service --debug
```

I discovered that our Cisco server wanted a domain name (DNS, not Active Directory), which can be configured on the Advanced tab in Network Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I started having the same problem one day on Xubuntu 14.04.

I've added the line `Enable Single DES` to the file `/etc/vpnc/default.conf`. This fixed it at first. Days later I had the same issue again. I tried removing that line and it worked again.

I can't tell if something changed on the VPN server side or not to cause this, but that resolved it for me.