# Mobile Wireless access point keeps dropping

Tags: wireless, network-manager, intel-wireless, wpa-supplicant

I have a Wireless access point on my phone that I've just set up. The phone is a Samsung Galaxy S2 provided by ATT Wireless.
When I first set it up, Network Manager recognized the access point and I was able to connect.

Then, a day or two later, The connection would only remain for about a minute. 
I have consulted the following links and none of the suggestions there have had any impact on my situation:

http://www.askubuntu.com/questions/117969/wifi-hotspot-disconnected-after-some-time
(there is no relevant information in this answer at all.)

[Can't connect VPN pptp on 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431311/solved-cant-connect-vpn-pptp-on-13-10)
(This is a VPN)

[Wifi connect problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342637/wifi-connect-problem)
(setting sudo iw wlan0 set power_save off had no effect)

I can maintain a connection to other wifi routers, home work etc. Just not the phone.

I am running the following system:

```
Linux 3.11.0-19-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP 
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:    13.10
Codename:   saucy
```

The driver (as provided by lspci) is:

```
Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)
```

Once I lose the connection, the device is no longer seen by the SSID scan. I have to restart wpa_supplicant in order to see it again and connect to it.

Tailing /var/log/syslog offers a few snippets of what is happening:

The initial successful connection:

```
Apr 21 22:57:59 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): bringing up device.
Apr 21 22:57:59 eggsmachine kernel: [18251.911641] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
Apr 21 22:57:59 eggsmachine kernel: [18251.911885] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
Apr 21 22:57:59 eggsmachine kernel: [18251.924021] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Apr 21 22:57:59 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0) supports 5 scan SSIDs
Apr 21 22:57:59 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Trying to remove a non-existant call id.
Apr 21 22:57:59 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Apr 21 22:57:59 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
Apr 21 22:57:59 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: ready -> inactive
Apr 21 22:57:59 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0) supports 5 scan SSIDs
Apr 21 22:58:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Activation (wlan0) starting connection 'eggmatters'
Apr 21 22:58:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Apr 21 22:58:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Apr 21 22:58:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Apr 21 22:58:14 eggsmachine whoopsie[1321]: offline
Apr 21 22:58:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Apr 21 22:58:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Apr 21 22:58:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Apr 21 22:58:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr 21 22:58:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'eggmatters' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Apr 21 22:58:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Config: added 'ssid' value 'eggmatters'
Apr 21 22:58:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Apr 21 22:58:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Apr 21 22:58:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Config: added 'psk' value ''
Apr 21 22:58:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Apr 21 22:58:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Apr 21 22:58:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[5029]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 20:64:32:3a:91:85 (SSID='eggmatters' freq=2462 MHz)
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[5029]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 20:64:32:3a:91:85 (SSID='eggmatters' freq=2462 MHz)
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine kernel: [18271.392061] wlan0: authenticate with 20:64:32:3a:91:85
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine kernel: [18271.392784] wlan0: send auth to 20:64:32:3a:91:85 (try 1/3)
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine kernel: [18271.394588] wlan0: authenticated
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine kernel: [18271.395117] wlan0: associate with 20:64:32:3a:91:85 (try 1/3)
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine kernel: [18271.398930] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 20:64:32:3a:91:85 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[5029]: wlan0: Associated with 20:64:32:3a:91:85
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine kernel: [18271.399687] wlan0: associated
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine kernel: [18271.399824] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[5029]: wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 20:64:32:3a:91:85 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[5029]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 20:64:32:3a:91:85 completed (auth) [id=0 id_str=]
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Activation (wlan0/wireless) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'eggmatters'.
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Activation (wlan0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  dhclient started with pid 5282
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine dhclient: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine dhclient: All rights reserved.
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine dhclient: 
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine dhclient: Listening on LPF/wlan0/a0:88:69:32:fd:d9
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine dhclient: Sending on   LPF/wlan0/a0:88:69:32:fd:d9
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.43.84 on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x78346b10)
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine dhclient: DHCPACK of 192.168.43.84 from 192.168.43.1
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine dhclient: bound to 192.168.43.84 -- renewal in 1469 seconds.
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): DHCPv4 state changed preinit -> reboot
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:    address 192.168.43.84
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:    prefix 24 (255.255.255.0)
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:    gateway 192.168.43.1
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:    hostname 'eggsmachine'
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:    nameserver '192.168.43.1'
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine avahi-daemon[909]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.43.84.
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine avahi-daemon[909]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Apr 21 22:58:18 eggsmachine avahi-daemon[909]: Registering new address record for 192.168.43.84 on wlan0.IPv4.
Apr 21 22:58:19 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): device state change: ip-config -> secondaries (reason 'none') [70 90 0]
Apr 21 22:58:19 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
Apr 21 22:58:19 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): device state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Apr 21 22:58:20 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Policy set 'eggmatters' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Apr 21 22:58:20 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Apr 21 22:58:20 eggsmachine dnsmasq[2018]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Apr 21 22:58:20 eggsmachine dnsmasq[2018]: using nameserver 192.168.43.1#53
Apr 21 22:58:20 eggsmachine avahi-daemon[909]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::a288:69ff:fe32:fdd9.
Apr 21 22:58:20 eggsmachine avahi-daemon[909]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Apr 21 22:58:20 eggsmachine avahi-daemon[909]: Registering new address record for fe80::a288:69ff:fe32:fdd9 on wlan0.*.
Apr 21 22:58:20 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Activation (wlan0) successful, device activated.
Apr 21 22:58:20 eggsmachine dbus[823]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Apr 21 22:58:20 eggsmachine whoopsie[1321]: offline
Apr 21 22:58:20 eggsmachine dbus[823]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Apr 21 22:58:20 eggsmachine whoopsie[1321]: online
Apr 21 22:58:21 eggsmachine whoopsie[1321]: online
Apr 21 22:58:27 eggsmachine ntpdate[5361]: adjust time server 91.189.94.4 offset -0.033826 sec
```

Then, in this instance, we lose the connection:

```
Apr 21 22:58:59 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[5029]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=20:64:32:3a:91:85 reason=4
Apr 21 22:58:59 eggsmachine kernel: [18311.899261] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Apr 21 22:58:59 eggsmachine kernel: [18311.901056] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Apr 21 22:58:59 eggsmachine kernel: [18311.901058] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Apr 21 22:58:59 eggsmachine kernel: [18311.901059] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Apr 21 22:58:59 eggsmachine kernel: [18311.901060] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Apr 21 22:58:59 eggsmachine kernel: [18311.901061] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Apr 21 22:58:59 eggsmachine kernel: [18311.901062] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Apr 21 22:58:59 eggsmachine kernel: [18311.901063] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Apr 21 22:58:59 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Apr 21 22:58:59 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Apr 21 22:59:11 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[5029]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 20:64:32:3a:91:85 (SSID='eggmatters' freq=2462 MHz)
Apr 21 22:59:11 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[5029]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 20:64:32:3a:91:85 (SSID='eggmatters' freq=2462 MHz)
Apr 21 22:59:11 eggsmachine kernel: [18324.400907] wlan0: authenticate with 20:64:32:3a:91:85
Apr 21 22:59:11 eggsmachine kernel: [18324.401919] wlan0: send auth to 20:64:32:3a:91:85 (try 1/3)
Apr 21 22:59:11 eggsmachine kernel: [18324.403932] wlan0: authenticated
Apr 21 22:59:11 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
Apr 21 22:59:11 eggsmachine kernel: [18324.408370] wlan0: associate with 20:64:32:3a:91:85 (try 1/3)
Apr 21 22:59:11 eggsmachine kernel: [18324.411832] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 20:64:32:3a:91:85 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
Apr 21 22:59:11 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[5029]: wlan0: Associated with 20:64:32:3a:91:85
Apr 21 22:59:11 eggsmachine kernel: [18324.412786] wlan0: associated
Apr 21 22:59:11 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): link timed out.
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): device state change: activated -> failed (reason 'supplicant-timeout') [100 120 11]
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Activation (wlan0) failed for connection 'eggmatters'
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine whoopsie[1321]: offline
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine dbus[823]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine dbus[823]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 5282
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine avahi-daemon[909]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::a288:69ff:fe32:fdd9 on wlan0.
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine avahi-daemon[909]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::a288:69ff:fe32:fdd9.
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine avahi-daemon[909]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine avahi-daemon[909]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.43.84 on wlan0.
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine avahi-daemon[909]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.43.84.
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine avahi-daemon[909]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine kernel: [18327.457293] wlan0: deauthenticating from 20:64:32:3a:91:85 by local choice (reason=3)
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  Removing DNS information from /sbin/resolvconf
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine dnsmasq[2018]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[5029]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 reason=3
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine kernel: [18327.459960] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine kernel: [18327.464927] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine kernel: [18327.464934] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine kernel: [18327.464939] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine kernel: [18327.464944] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine kernel: [18327.464947] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine kernel: [18327.464950] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine kernel: [18327.464953] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Apr 21 22:59:14 eggsmachine NetworkManager[930]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
```

For "CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=20:64:32:3a:91:85 reason=4", I can't find a resource that explains what reason=4 means.

We do see that on the subsequent retry, the link times out with a CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 reason=3

Which makes sense as wpa_supplicant can no longer find the device.

I can repeat this process by running:

```
ps -ef | grep wpa
kill -9 (the pid of wpa_supplicant)
```

Adding verbose logging to wpa_supplicant shows the following:

```
Apr 23 09:07:31 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[4790]: WPA: drop TX EAPOL in non-IEEE 802.1X mode (type=1 len=0)
Apr 23 09:07:40 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[4790]: EAPOL: External notification - portEnabled=0
Apr 23 09:07:40 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[4790]: EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state DISCONNECTED
Apr 23 09:07:40 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[4790]: EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
Apr 23 09:07:40 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[4790]: EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state INITIALIZE
Apr 23 09:07:40 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[4790]: EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
Apr 23 09:07:40 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[4790]: EAPOL: External notification - portValid=0
Apr 23 09:07:40 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[4790]: EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
Apr 23 09:07:40 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[4790]: EAPOL: External notification - EAP success=0
Apr 23 09:07:40 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[4790]: EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
Apr 23 09:07:40 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[4790]: EAPOL: External notification - portEnabled=0
Apr 23 09:07:40 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[4790]: EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
Apr 23 09:07:40 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[4790]: EAPOL: External notification - portValid=0
Apr 23 09:07:40 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[4790]: EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
Apr 23 09:07:40 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[4790]: EAPOL: External notification - EAP success=0
Apr 23 09:07:40 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[4790]: EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
Apr 23 09:07:40 eggsmachine wpa_supplicant[4790]: EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
```

So whatever EAPOL is, it's not authenticating anymore.

So as a quick recap:

- Cannot connect to mobil wireless (Samsung Galaxy S2 via ATT) for more than 1-5 minutes
- Can connect to other wireless access points without issue.
- Logs indicate device can't authenticate and times out.

Other forum posts indicate either a kernel issue or a device driver issue. My situation is confusing as I can connect to wifi hotspots.

Oh, and I'm not entirely sure if it's the phone or not. I haven't yet tested it on other devices. My instincts are telling me that it's not the phone.

Thanks for taking the time to help me with this. Just migrated from Debian Wheezy to Ubuntu, so . . . that's of no use whatsoever but, this is my first Ask Ubuntu post.

UPDATE:
I've removed the MAC ADDRESS for this machine from the phone, and just simply authenticate with WPA2. That, obviously, did nothing.

The logs seem to indicate that the device no longer honors the authenticity of the connection. In trying to isolate wpa_supplicant, I've called wpa_supplicant from the terminal, passing in driver, and ssid but that mucks with NetworkManager which is running it's own version of wpa_supplicant and apparently, they don't play nice.

The other culprit may be dnsmasq, as it looks like it's querying my phone for a dns entry and maybe those two aren't interacting very well "I'd like a dns entry. Sure. I'd like a dns entry again. Wait a second, I just gave you one two minutes ago."

Daily bump: Don't you just love it when well-formed issues providing background and logs as well as histories and log go unnoticed? So, the connection is stable and continuous when tethered. Something is up with the signal then. Maybe it's a bad driver? Not sure as this question is pretty fallow.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a Kernel bug for the realtek wireless device drivers.  I am having the same issue on Ubuntu 14.04 with my connection dropping.  I am getting ready to revert to an older kernel version to see if that solves my issues.  I hope you find help with your issue. Wildman and I are troubleshooting my issue on the thread [Wifi Drops and Reconnects with UBUNTU 14.04 (Realtek RTL8188)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500310/wifi-drops-and-reconnects-with-ubuntu-14-04-realtek-rtl8188), we have documented our steps along the way, maybe you can try some of what we have tried and find a solution if you issue is similar enough to mine.