# Slow wifi ubuntu 20.04 I'm getting only 20Mbps should be getting 300Mbps

Tags: networking, wireless

So after 4 hours of reading and trying to solve this on my own I do believe I have found the issue that's causing the slow wifi on my 2015 custom built PC. I'm pretty sure the issue is this, I think ubuntu is detecting the wrong wireless card, when I check in terminal what the wireless network is it says "Realtek RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter" but the wireless card that I have installed on this PC is the ASUS PCE-N15 wireless card.

But get this, on this asus wireless card there is a realtek chip, (I mean I'm pretty sure there is a realtek chip on it). I went to the Asus website and indeed Asus has drivers for the PCE-N15 wireless card for the linux OS, and I downloaded these drivers and then I extracted them using 7zip. Then I started taking a look inside the folder that I extracted and found another folder with the name "RTL8192CE". RTL8192CE is the name of the realtek wireless card that ubuntu detects in terminal when I run the command.

There are no wifi drivers that show up in "additional drivers" I already checked.

I've only been using ubuntu linux for about 6 months on this PC. Before I had been using windows 8.1 and I can't remember what it said for wireless network and I can't remember if I ever had to download wifi drivers, I dont think I did cause windows just worked right out the box (I wiped the drive and reinstalled the OS many times on this custom built PC of mine when I used windows). So my point is ubuntu is telling me in terminal that my wireless network is "realtek RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter". I used to have windows installed on this PC and I can't remember what it said for wireless network but I was checking out the amazon reviews for the Asus PCE-N15 wireless card (keep in mind what I have installed on my computer is the Asus PCE-N15) and I found a screen shot someone took of their network properties on windows 10 and it says "Asus PCE_N15" look at the picture
[image: Asus PCE_N15 wireless card]

I hope I'm not confusing you the reader whose reading this. There is a chip on the Asus PCE-N15 wireless card and I do believe it's a realtek chip. I think ubuntu is detecting the realtek chip but it should be telling me that it's detecting the Asus PCE-N15, not the realtek chip.

Here's a screenshot of the Asus website where I found the linux drivers for the Asus PCE-N15 wireless card.
[image: Asus website screenshot]

So I googled "realtek RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter drivers" and look what I found on one website which I took a screenshot of, notice how it says

Subsystem: ASUSTek Computer / PCE-N15 11n Wireless LAN PCIe Card

[image: realtek screenshot]

So yeah I'm at the point where I want to pull my hair out. My wifi should be getting at least 300Mbps but it's only doing 20Mbps. But like I said I found the linux drivers for the Asus PCE-N15 wireless card
https://www.asus.com/us/Networking-IoT-Servers/Adapters/All-series/PCEN15/HelpDesk_Download/ and I downloaded it but I don't know how to install them on ubuntu?

I was referring a lot to this when I was trying to solve this on my own https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html.en this is where I got this terminal command `lspci`

This is the ouput of `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780 Host Bridge
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (ext gfx port 0)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 3)
00:0a.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 5)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 3c)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 5
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 High Definition Audio Controller [GeForce 940MX] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042A USB 3.0 Host Controller
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 09)
```

So what can I do? Please ask me if you need more info. On this 2015 custom built PC i have the the Asus PCE-N15 wireless card installed and before I was using ubuntu linux i was using windows, only recently in the last 6 months I decided to wipe the drive and install ubuntu. If I remember correctly for the network settings back when I had windows it would show me "Asus PCE-N15 wireless card" but ubuntu is showing me that my wireless network is "Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter". And I am pretty sure that there is a realtek chip on the Asus wireless card, if you look at a picture of the Asuse PCE-N15 wireless card you can see there is a tiny black chip on it.
[image]

Ask me if you need more information. What can I do?

edit:

Here's the output when I enter in terminal command `nmcli device wifi list`

```
joe@joe-System-Product-Name:~$ nmcli device wifi list
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID            MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BAR>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  82      ▂▄▆>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  Kavika2019      Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  77      ▂▄▆>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  77      ▂▄▆>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  6     65 Mbit/s   75      ▂▄▆>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  74      ▂▄▆>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  HOME-7A55-2.4   Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  74      ▂▄▆>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  11    65 Mbit/s   72      ▂▄▆>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  winstonravioli  Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  70      ▂▄▆>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  67      ▂▄▆>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  Portlandia      Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  64      ▂▄▆>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  NETGEAR93       Infra  2     405 Mbit/s  64      ▂▄▆>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  62      ▂▄▆>
*       xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  ARRIS-15D1      Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  60      ▂▄▆>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  6     260 Mbit/s  60      ▂▄▆>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  6     260 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  6     260 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  Pumpkin         Infra  6     260 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  SnakeEater      Infra  6     260 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄_>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  6     260 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄_>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  6     260 Mbit/s  50      ▂▄_>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄_>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  HOME-EC92       Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄_>
lines 1-23...skipping...
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID            MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY         
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  82      ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2        
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  Kavika2019      Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  77      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  77      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2        
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  6     65 Mbit/s   75      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  74      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 802.1X 
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  HOME-7A55-2.4   Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  74      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2        
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  11    65 Mbit/s   72      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  winstonravioli  Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  70      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  67      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2        
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  Portlandia      Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  64      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  NETGEAR93       Infra  2     405 Mbit/s  64      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  62      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 802.1X 
*       xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  ARRIS-15D1      Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  60      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  6     260 Mbit/s  60      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  6     260 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆_  WPA2 802.1X      
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  6     260 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  Pumpkin         Infra  6     260 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  SnakeEater      Infra  6     260 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  6     260 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  6     260 Mbit/s  50      ▂▄__  WPA2 802.1X      
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  HOME-EC92       Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2        

-----

IN-USE  BSSID              SSID            MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY         
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  82      ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2        
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  Kavika2019      Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  77      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  77      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2        
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  6     65 Mbit/s   75      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  74      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 802.1X 
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  HOME-7A55-2.4   Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  74      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2        
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  11    65 Mbit/s   72      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  winstonravioli  Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  70      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  67      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2        
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  Portlandia      Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  64      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  NETGEAR93       Infra  2     405 Mbit/s  64      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  62      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 802.1X 
*       xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  ARRIS-15D1      Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  60      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  6     260 Mbit/s  60      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  6     260 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆_  WPA2 802.1X      
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  6     260 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  Pumpkin         Infra  6     260 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  SnakeEater      Infra  6     260 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  6     260 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  6     260 Mbit/s  50      ▂▄__  WPA2 802.1X      
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --              Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  WPA2             
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  HOME-EC92       Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2        
~
```

Output when I enter command `ip link`

```
joe@joe-System-Product-Name:~$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp4s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Output when I enter terminal command `iwconfig`

```
joe@joe-System-Product-Name:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"ARRIS-15D1"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX   
          Bit Rate=144.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:49   Missed beacon:0

joe@joe-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo iwconfig <interface> power off
bash: interface: No such file or directory
joe@joe-System-Product-Name:~$
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134989/discussion-on-question-by-danny-slow-wifi-ubuntu-20-04-im-getting-only-20mbps-s).

Answer (score 0):

You are focusing on Network tools but I don't see [`iwconfig`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iwconfig) being mentioned, which specifically deals with WiFi setup.

Usually when something like this happens it's because:

- The driver is crap
- Power management. `sudo iwconfig <interface> power off`
- Bad sensitivity thresholds. See `sudo iwconfig <interface> sens <threshold>`
- Bad mode. `sudo iwconfig <interface> modu <standard>` Literally lets you set the 802.11 mode. Auto may be choosing the worst one instead of the best one.
- Freq & Channels: Routers offer various freq & channels (sometimes they're locked on a particular one though). Due to legal regulations (or misconfigurations) not all channels may be available in your region (i.e. your router provides channels that your client thinks is not legally allowed to use). Furthermore, your client may not support the channel your router is offering. When this happens, your WiFi tries to fallback to older norms until it finds something it can use. Try manually setting the channels in both router and your client, for your client it's `sudo iwconfig <interface> channel <#>`

The manual has more options for you to try.

Additionally `sudo iwconfig <interface>` may just tell if there's something wrong.

Looking for solutions for your chip (instead of typing ASUS) reveals [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/500421/274245). I don't know if it will work or if I can recommend it.

Other [suggestions online](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=344853) attempt to use `ips=0 fwlps=0 aspm=0` instead.

May be some of these settings work for you.

Comment: I appreciate the help but I'm going to get some sleep and try these options tomorrow and I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: My computer is using the Asus PCE-N15 wireless card and on the Asus website there are even linux drivers for the Asus PCE-N15 that can be downloaded. It's all in the post I describe it in detail and even post the link. Isn't there any proprietary driver that I could use? I actually downloaded the linux drivers for the Asus PCE-N15 from the asus website and I took a look inside the file and I found a folder named "RTL8192CE". RTL8192CE is the name of the realtek wireless card that ubuntu detects in terminal when I run the command. Can you see what I'm getting at?

Comment: I took a quick glance at the driver provided by ASUS and it appears to be an older version of the same driver provided with the Linux kernel under `drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi` folder. Try what I said.

Comment: wait a second, how did you find those drivers for the realtek rtlwifi, where did those come from? And please you laid out many options for me to try and I'm feeling confused what should I try first tell me exactly what to do first and be as detailed as possible, I'm a lifelong Windows user so I'm totally new to Linux and the whole terminal thing. I never used terminal in windows. Thanks for your help. It's just you laid out several options and I'm feeling confused, like where do I start? Be detailed please.

Comment: Hey you still there? Listen I entered in `iwconfig` in my terminal and I edited my post to include the output of said command. Power management is on but I don't know what to enter in for "interface", take a look you'll see what I'm talking about. Please help me? Also understand I'm a novice when it comes to linux and terminal. I've been a lifelong windows user.

Comment: @Danny i notice that there is a lot of traffic on channel 6 on your wifi network,maybe changing your router to an other channel like CH 8 where there is no interference from other routers might help get you up to speed :)

Comment: @Matias N Goldberg Ok i figured how to turn off the power management using the command you told me but it didn't work at all and when I restart the computer the power management says "on", so it won't stay off but it doesn't matter because it doesn't do anything, I'm still getting 20Mbps when I should be getting 300Mbps. Is there anyway I can install the linux drivers from the Asus website? Why would Asus offer linux drivers if I can't install them, can I install them? Please help me but please be detailed in your answers so I don't get confused.

Comment: @trondhansen Thanks for the help but how do I switch to CH 8? Do I have to switch channels on my router, like do I do that on the router itself?

Comment: you need to look at the manufactorers website or in the users manual for your router to find the routers adress to log in and change the channel,you can do it from your pc.

Comment: https://www.hellotech.com/guide/for/how-to-change-wifi-channel-on-router

Comment: @trondhansen I changed to channel 8, it had no effect. Listen read my post very carefully though you'll see that Asus has drivers for my wifi card for LINUX that you can download. I downloaded them but I don't know how to install them, can I even install them? Please read my post very carefully you'll see what I'm talking about and I even provided the link to it. Why would Asus have linux drivers for the wifi card that's in my computer for download? Because when I used to use windows that's the drivers I would use except it would be for windows instead of linux.