# Slow wifi download speeds on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless, 22.04

First things first, I tried to get this problem solved (with no luck) when i was using Ubuntu 20.04, look here [Slow wifi ubuntu 20.04 I'm getting only 20Mbps should be getting 300Mbps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398784/slow-wifi-ubuntu-20-04-im-getting-only-20mbps-should-be-getting-300mbps)

So as you can see on 20.04 I was having slow wifi and I tried to get it solved  but couldn't, so I thought that hopefully 22.04 would solve the slow wifi issue, that was my hope anyways, but I'm on 22.04 and the wifi is still slow. And it's only the download speeds that are slow, the upload speed is fine. I'm getting about a 30Mbps download speed when it should be about 300Mbps. Oh one more thing, over a wired connection my download speed is about 500Mbps so the wired connection is totally fine, it's my wifi that's got a problem.

Personally I think the wifi driver is bad that's what I think. I'm hoping to get this solved here on askubuntu, if I can't get it solved then I'm going to report this to Canonical as a bug. But hopefully it's not a bug and one of you can help me solve this once and for all.

This is the ouput of `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780 Host Bridge
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (ext gfx port 0)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 3)
00:0a.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 5)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 3c)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 5
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 High Definition Audio Controller [GeForce 940MX] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042A USB 3.0 Host Controller
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 09)
```

Here's the output when I enter in terminal command `nmcli device wifi list`

```
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID                            MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY         
*       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  ARRIS-15D1                      Infra  8     270 Mbit/s  94      ▂▄▆█  WPA2             
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  --                              Infra  11    260 Mbit/s  89      ▂▄▆█  WPA2             
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  Kavika2019                      Infra  11    260 Mbit/s  87      ▂▄▆█  WPA2             
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  --                              Infra  11    260 Mbit/s  87      ▂▄▆█  WPA2             
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  --                              Infra  11    260 Mbit/s  87      ▂▄▆█  WPA2 802.1X      
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  --                              Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  79      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  --                              Infra  1     195 Mbit/s  77      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2        
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  --                              Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  77      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  --                              Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  77      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 802.1X 
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  carlos                          Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  62      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  --                              Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  62      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2        
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  --                              Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  62      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 802.1X 
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  --                              Infra  1     195 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 802.1X 
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  HOME-7A55-2.4                   Infra  1     195 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2        
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  --                              Infra  1     195 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2        
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  Daxs House                      Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  --                              Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 802.1X 
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  --                              Infra  11    260 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  WPA2 802.1X      
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  Pumpkin                         Infra  11    260 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  WPA2             
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  --                              Infra  11    260 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  WPA2             
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  --                              Infra  11    260 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  WPA2             
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  --                              Infra  11    260 Mbit/s  49      ▂▄__  WPA2             
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  HP-Print-E2-Officejet Pro 8600  Infra  6     54 Mbit/s   47      ▂▄__  WPA2             
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  Cfyuuy6fff                      Infra  11    260 Mbit/s  47      ▂▄__  WPA2             
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  --                              Infra  10    270 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA2             
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  HOME-EC92                       Infra  11    270 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2
```

Output when I enter command `ip link`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp4s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Output when I enter terminal command `iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"ARRIS-15D1"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.447 GHz  Access Point: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX   
          Bit Rate=144.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=66/70  Signal level=-44 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:102   Missed beacon:0
```

**Edit:**

output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8178] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1043:85e3]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce
    Kernel modules: rtl8192ce
```

Output of `iwlist wlp2s0 freq`

```
wlp2s0    11 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)
```

**Edit:**

So what does the link speed mean exactly? Why is it 144Mbps? I thought my wifi router was capable of 300Mbps. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to replace all of `lspci` with `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and to add the result of: `iwlist wlp2s0 freq`

Comment: @chili555 Ok I did.

Answer (score 0):

First, I disagree entirely with the advice given at your other question to use channel 8 in the router. Channel 8 is an overlapped channel. Please see: https://www.metageek.com/training/resources/why-channels-1-6-11/ Based on the channel density at your location, I recommend channel 1.

Next, there are some troubleshooting steps that you should consider. Check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Please check the antenna connectors to your wireless card. Are both securely snapped into place?

[image]

Typically, there is a small door on the bottom of your laptop by which you can see the wireless card.

Finally, the rtl8192ce device is not capable of 5 gHz operation, typically the fastest method. Please see the Full Device Details here: https://device.report/wifi/WFA8643

You could certainly consider a 5 gHz capable USB wireless instead of the internal device.

Comment: Hey it says here that it should be able to get 300Mbps down https://www.amazon.com/ASUS-PCE-N15-performance-Wireless-N-interface/dp/B0053GR2YI So I did implement the changes to the wifi that you recommended and it actually made it slower now, now it's only getting about 15Mbps down, what's funny is the down speed is slower than the up speed which is about 20Mbps up. This is so funny. Is there anything else I should try? Should I turn power mode off? Also I made an edit to the post where I have a question so please check that out. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I am thinking about getting a 5 gHZ USB wireless but I'd like to get this thing to work if I can. Do you think the wifi driver might me bad? I am seriously thinking about reporting this as a bug to Canonical.