# Wifi was working fine but I messed with the router settings and now wifi won't connect Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless, 22.04

So I've been having slow Wi-Fi and you can see that here [Slow wifi download speeds on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1449245/slow-wifi-download-speeds-on-ubuntu-22-04/1449387#1449387) So I was trying to fix the slow Wi-Fi, one of the things I did was I messed with the router settings, like I changed channels on the router and did a few other things, but the Wi-Fi should be connecting, none of the settings I messed with on the router should prevent my PC from connecting. Here's what's going on, the networks are showing up and when I click to sign into my Wi-Fi network it says "connecting" and then it'll say failed to connect and then it'll try to connect again and then tell me it failed to connect, and then it'll try to connect again and tell me it failed to connect, and it will keep doing this in a loop until eventually it stops trying to connect to the Wi-Fi. I've tried everything at this point, I rebooted the computer, I have hit "forget Wi-Fi network" and re-entered the password. It seems to be bugged.

Is there a way to reset the Wi-Fi?

Comment: There are some missing things, for example the name/model of your router. However can you go to your router settings and check under MAC filtering. I think you blocked your device's MAC address from connecting or you enabled a feature whereby only authorised MAC filters will connect and the MAC address of your laptop was not listed.

Comment: @MoyoFreeman this might be worth checking out for more information about my situation, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398784/slow-wifi-ubuntu-20-04-im-getting-only-20mbps-should-be-getting-300mbps I don't think it's my router's fault, but my router is an Arris SBG10, again I don't think it's my router's fault here because my smartphones are still accessing the Wi-Fi. I truly think this is Ubuntu's fault. I have experienced so many bugs with Ubuntu it's not even funny.