# VPN Connection problem with vpnc

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, vpn, thinkpad

I was able to work through the VPN using network-manager-vpnc without any problem but suddenly it stopped working. This is a snippet caught from my syslog:

```
Sep  2 10:58:19 chachan-ThinkPad-L420 NetworkManager[1130]: <info> Starting VPN service 'vpnc'...
Sep  2 10:58:19 chachan-ThinkPad-L420 NetworkManager[1130]: <info> VPN service 'vpnc' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.vpnc), PID 16516
Sep  2 10:58:19 chachan-ThinkPad-L420 NetworkManager[1130]: <info> VPN service 'vpnc' appeared; activating connections
Sep  2 10:58:19 chachan-ThinkPad-L420 NetworkManager[1130]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
Sep  2 10:58:19 chachan-ThinkPad-L420 NetworkManager[1130]: <info> VPN connection 'ABCXYZ' (Connect) reply received.
Sep  2 10:58:19 chachan-ThinkPad-L420 NetworkManager[1130]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Sep  2 10:58:19 chachan-ThinkPad-L420 NetworkManager[1130]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Sep  2 10:58:19 chachan-ThinkPad-L420 NetworkManager[1130]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Sep  2 10:58:34 chachan-ThinkPad-L420 avahi-daemon[1085]: Withdrawing workstation service for tun0.
Sep  2 10:58:34 chachan-ThinkPad-L420 NetworkManager[1130]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Sep  2 10:58:34 chachan-ThinkPad-L420 NetworkManager[1130]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Sep  2 10:58:34 chachan-ThinkPad-L420 NetworkManager[1130]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)
Sep  2 10:58:34 chachan-ThinkPad-L420 NetworkManager[1130]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
Sep  2 10:58:34 chachan-ThinkPad-L420 NetworkManager[1130]: <info> Policy set 'WirelessLink' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Sep  2 10:58:34 chachan-ThinkPad-L420 NetworkManager[1130]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Sep  2 10:58:39 chachan-ThinkPad-L420 NetworkManager[1130]: <info> VPN service 'vpnc' disappeared
```

I tried rebooting, restarting wireless and restarting networking. Any idea what else I could test or do?.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have the same problem. I was able to get some useful debug output by running:

```
sudo /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-vpnc-service --debug
```

from: https://wiki.gnome.org/NetworkManager/Debugging and then connecting to the vpn in network manager. Unfortunately that just let me fix my problem with vpnc-connect working slightly better than network-manager-vpnc using the instructions on [Cisco VPN not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144205/cisco-vpn-not-working) about 1des but not make it actually work as I don't know what to do with the debug output talking about ESP packets. Perhaps this will help you.